# Jquery Full screen background

Tags: jquery, fullscreen

I try for searching for Full screen background with click events with cool animation.

The full screen is not slide. For example when I'm on homepage with "first full screen image" then when I click to the different page the full screen will change with cool animation.

I try searching for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

- [Vegas](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/)
- [Backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/)
- [Supersized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/)
- http://bavotasan.com/demos/fullbg/
- Check out [this article](http://www.freshdesignweb.com/fullscreen-jquery-slider.html)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for this http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

Here's a demo: http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html

Comment: @Jows: Let me know if it worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [jQuery Vegas](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/). Here's the [demo page](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/demo/). I believe there's option to fulfill your need.